# If check in rails form tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

```
<%= form.text_field :email, :value => @customer.email_primary  %>
```

I need to put a if check before the value so it doesn't pass unless the customer is logged in. I know the if is if `logged_in?`, but I can't get my syntax right.

Comment: Give an attempt to `<%= form.text_field :email, :value => (@customer.logged_in ? @customer.email_primary : "")  %>` I'm not sure if it'll work.

Comment: no good, but closer to what i'm looking for since it's inside the tag.  THanks for the try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% if @customer.logged_in? %>
<%= form.text_field :email, :value => @customer.email_primary  %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry I should of been more specific.I know how to wrap the entire tag in a if, Is it not possible to put the if inside the form tag before the value?

Answer (score 0):

While there is an accepted answer, I think the OP was looking for this:

```
<%= form.text_field :email, :value => @customer.email_primary if @customer.logged_in?  %>
```